# Periods in UX/UI microcopy?

Tags: copywriting

What are your thoughts on where terminal punctuation should be used in microcopy? Titles, touts, and help text, error messages, bulleted lists…

I tend to think periods only have a place in body text or paragraphs, or in any instance where the is more than one sentence. We're currently having a polite debate about the attached image. What do you think?[image]

Answer (score 10):

#### For material design, their guidelines recommend no periods on one sentence of UI text.

I don't have access to research verifying the material guidelines, but here is their viewpoint on making text concise and readable:

From **[Material Design writing](https://material.io/design/communication/writing.html#principles)**

[image]

[image]

**[Salesforce's lightning design system](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_pubs_style_guide.meta/salesforce_pubs_style_guide/style_periods.htm):**

> Omit the period after items in a bulleted or other type of list only if the items are fragments rather than complete sentences. However, a period is necessary at the end of a sentence whenever more than one sentence exists for that bullet. In this case, make all bullets complete sentences that end in periods so that each bullet is parallel.

Again, I don't have cited research links, but these are organizations that have put in research into a large amount of design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure about the wording (and I don't think this is good wording for a hyperlink, but that's a different discussion), I would keep the excalamation point, and explore different ways to demonstrate the CTA's function - making it into a button, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things that you'll see everybody doing but it's hard to find anybody trying to define in an article because it's such a broad subject.

**Don't use punctuation.** Only use it to separate sentences in bodies of text.

This issue is really broad. I guess the main thing is that UIs are different than text even though they're full of text. In general, UIs are like graphics, not text.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale could lay in the history of punctuation. Full stop `.` was invented to separate sentences. So don't use it if there is nothing to separate.